# Add a cron-function to wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cron

I'd like to add an own cron to wordpress.

It shall run with the normal wp-cron and do the following code:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');
```

How can I add my own cron-function to wp-cron?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you want to loop through all posts on the site and replace that URL? is it ONE time? Can you add more the purpose of this search/replace so we can get context if it is one time, or ongoing, and if it is one post at a time, or you going to loop through all posts say everyday .. etc..

Comment: I need to run the replace once or twice a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress wp-cron is a pseudo cron. It's run scheduled functions everytime when **somebody enter** page.

Why do you want update `post_content`? If it's connected with wordpress site migration consider [Moving WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).

If you realy need change URL in posts, try do it every time when you save new post:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_data' , '99', 2 );

function filter_post_data( $data , $postarr ) {
    //post content is in $data array.
    //Look for URL in $data['post_content'], replace it and return modified $data.

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This code is great!
But I need it mostly for old posts. Not for new posts. So a cron would be nice, which edits all old posts once or twice a day.
The problem is, that on my site user can edit old posts. And I need to change the edits.

Comment: Ok, so I sugest you check that is your hosting have cron enabled. If so, create simple php file that connect to DB with data from your wp-config, and run only that one SQL code which you wrote, and run php file with your cron. WP-cron will run action before render page for user, so if you have big collection of posts, delay would be noticeable. By the way, did URL change is so often, that is needed to run it daily?

Comment: Thank you! Solved it with your way.